# Does the operation $(A\times B) \cup (B\times A)$ have its own name?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I use such an operation a lot in a computer program I write and I was wondering if it has its own mathematical name. That's all. I was looking for "commutative cartesian product" and for some other similar things in Google but I haven't find anything of that sort so I suspect that this operation remains unnamed. Thank you in advance for your response.